# SSD fstrim and encrypted home folder, unencrypted root, how should I setup trim for home?

Tags: encryption, ssd

I have /etc/cryptab but only swap partition listed here. Had set up trim root partition in cron, its not encrypted.  What about home folder? Its encrypted but not a partition, but mounted somehow I think, should I setup trim for it? How?

I have read similar questions, but not found exact information, but at least found to setup trim for unencrypted root.

Its encrypted as default behavior in ubuntu installer - "encrypt home folder"

```
leonid@LeonidMew:~$ cat /etc/crypttab 
# <target name> <source device>     <key file>  <options>
cryptswap1 /swapfile /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64

leonid@LeonidMew:~$ mount
/dev/sdb1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
...skip...
/home/.ecryptfs/leonid/.Private on /home/leonid type ecryptfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=...,ecryptfs_sig=...,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Home folders are not partitions but mounted at user login if encrypted. I have check, it doesn't support trim, so it's not needed for encrypted folders.

If you have home as separate partition, encrypted, answer could be different. But it easy to check does it support trim or not.

Also, there are **fstrim --all in cron weekly**(anacron) in latest ubuntu, so nothing to worry about.